# Is there a shortcut for System.out.println on Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, shortcut

I have seen that on Ecplise you can type sysout and then the shortcut will change to `System.out.println();`

I was wondering if there was a shortcut like this for Netbeans(currently 8.1).

Comment: "sout' is the keyword.
 
Additionally, if "soutv" it would look something like below.

`System.out.println("something = " + something);`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Type "sout" then hit tab.

See https://netbeans.org/project_downloads/usersguide/shortcuts-80.pdf

Comment: Hi @Dimi as this is your first question, you must know: if this or any answer has solved your question please **consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark.** This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and **gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself**. Of course, there is no obligation to do this. And IMO this should be the accedpted answer because is prior to mine.

Comment: The link is now https://netbeans.apache.org/tutorials/70/nbm-code-template.html and for other ide stuff https://netbeans.apache.org/kb/docs/java/editor-codereference.html

Answer (score 6):

Just write:

**sout** + <kbd>tab</kbd>

[SOURCE](https://netbeans.org/project_downloads/usersguide/shortcuts-73.pdf).

Comment: Or you can just type  some part of the code you would like to use and hit ** Ctrl + Space **

Comment: @HasS NetBeans is not Eclipse ;) autocomplete exists, but netbeas has it's owns codetemplates rules